# Finite difference approximations in python

Tags: python, math, calculus

I am trying to calculate the derivative of a function at x = 0, but I keep getting odd answers with all functions I have tried. For example with f(x)=x**2 I get the derivative to be 2 at all points. My finite difference coefficients are correct, it is second order accurate for the second derivative with respect to x.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

def f1(x):
    return x**2

n = 100 # grid points

x = zeros(n+1,dtype=float) # array to store values of x
step = 0.02/float(n) # step size
f = zeros(n+1,dtype=float) # array to store values of f
df = zeros(n+1,dtype=float) # array to store values of calulated derivative

for i in range(0,n+1): # adds values to arrays for x and f(x)
    x[i] = -0.01 + float(i)*step
    f[i] = f1(x[i])

# have to calculate end points seperately using one sided form

df[0] = (f[2]-2*f[1]+f[0])/step**2
df[1] = (f[3]-2*f[2]+f[1])/step**2
df[n-1] = (f[n-1]-2*f[n-2]+f[n-3])/step**2
df[n] = (f[n]-2*f[n-1]+f[n-2])/step**2

for i in range(2,n-1): # add values to array for derivative
    df[i] = (f[i+1]-2*f[i]+f[i-1])/step**2

print df # returns an array full of 2...
```

Comment: Have you tried print-debugging? (debugging by adding calls to `print` on intermediate values)

Comment: @Danra I have tried and the problem seems to occur when calculating df[i]. I have no idea why because the actual calculation should be correct, and I have tried on a calculator but I get the same answer. The maths is correct so I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: @Danra using the debugger is a better idea

Answer (score 2):

The second derivative of x^2 is the constant 2, and you use the central difference quotient for the second derivative, as you can also see by the square in the denominator. Your result is absolutely correct, your code does exactly what you told it to do.

To get the first derivative with a symmetric difference quotient, use

```
df[i] = ( f[i+1] - f[i-1] ) / ( 2*step )
```

Comment: I did indeed mean the second derivative but forgot I meant the second derivative so I was checking all the values as wrong. Thank for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

first order derivative at point x of function f1 (for the case f1(x)=x^2) can be obtained:

```
def f1(x):

    return (x**2)

def derivative (f, x, step=0.0000000000001):

    return ((f(x+step)-f(x))/step)
```

hope that helps